# Poor word recognition containing combination of digits and alphabets with OCR using tesseract.js

Tags: javascript, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, tesseract.js

I am using OCR technique to read words in receipts which generally contains combination of both alphabets and numerical digits like S3AB45, Z54GA. I am trying to do this in frontend only in Javascript using [tesseract.js](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js) but i am getting unexpected results.

For example:
Input word: S356 output => 8356

I guess S is replaced by 8 due to post processing by Tesseract.

So i tried to disable the dictionary model use but its not working.
 Here is my source code:

```
    $(function(){
    var file = $('#img-canvas');
    Tesseract.recognize(file,{
                load_system_dawg:0,
                load_freq_dawg:0,
                load_number_dawg:0,

            })
            .then(function(result){
            $('#ocr-res').html(result.text);
        });

});
```

I am not sure if the above issue is because of dictionary word match.Am i using wrong parameters here or is there any other way of resolving this issue?

Comment: You're asking people to debug your code without providing a full example, e.g. your example data / image for the 'file' var. Try adding a working snippet to your question.

Comment: actually other part of the code is not required this scenario any ways i will add other parts too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to disable the parameters which did not worked for me. But i got an alternative solution for this problem.

I looked into the OCR output result which is in JSON format and found out that it contains BLock, line and word information. Each word and their characters also contain their corresponding confidence values so i replaced their values from their alternative choices having highest confidence value. This method also helped in improving the overall accuracy of my OCR result.

For example: in 8356 : 8 had multiple choices like S,8,$,3 with S having highest confidence value so i replaced 8 with S and so 8356 -> S356.